# Complex join in CI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm developing an application in CI and here is my query echo which is not returning any output

```
SELECT `institute`.`name`
     , `user`.`username`
     , `ambassador`.`recommended_by`
     , `ambassador`.`degree_level`
     , `ambassador`.`about`
     , `ambassador`.`is_active`
     , `ambassador`.`added_on`
FROM `user`
    INNER JOIN `ambassador` ON `ambassador`.`user_id` = `user`.`id`
           AND `ambassador`.`recommended_by` = `user`.`id` 
    INNER JOIN `institute` ON `ambassador`.`institute_id` = `institute`.`id
```

**Explanation:**

Table names

- Users ( contain both data for all users added by type (
  ambassador/admin )
- institute ( content Institute data )
- Ambassador (
  this is where the data from both above tables is stored )

**Real quiz:**

I'm able to get the data which is sent to Ambassador table as IDs as the structure of the table is built like that. But on the view part I don't want to display those IDs i.e

- ambassador name **( user.user_type = Ambassador )** &
- **Instutue name** and
- ambassador name **(user.user_type = admin )**

I'm very much hopefull to get some help from here.

**Update:**

**Ambassador Table:**

```
id  
user_id
institute_id
degree_level
recommended_by
about
added_on
is_active
```

**User Table:**

```
id
first_name
last_name
username
email
password
gender
cnic
user_type
```

**Institute Table**

```
id
name
city_id
group_name
```

**Update Again**

For now, following query is working for me but I'm Looking for some efficient solution.

```
$this->db->select(
'institute.name,
user.username,
ambassador.id,
ambassador.degree_level,
ambassador.about,ambassador.is_active,ambassador.added_on');

    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->join('ambassador', 'ambassador.user_id = user.id', 'INNER');

$this->db->join('institute', 'ambassador.institute_id = institute.id', 'INNER');

    $query['q1'] = $this->db->get();
    $this->db->select('
    user.username');
```

**Second Query**

```
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->join('ambassador', 'ambassador.recommended_by=user.id', 'INNER');
    $query['q2'] = $this->db->get();
```

**Another Try: **
Now trying subqueries, not sure if this is correct or not. Any help would be appreciated in correcting this.

```
SELECT
(
SELECT
    `a`.id,
    `i`.`name`,
    `u`.`username`,
    `a`.`degree_level`,
    `a`.`recommended_by`,
    `a`.`about`,
    `a`.`is_active`,
    `a`.added_on
),
(
    SELECT
        `u`.`username`
    FROM
        `user`
    WHERE
        `user_type` = "admin"
    )
FROM
    `user` AS `u`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `institute` AS `i`
ON
    `a`.`institute_id` = `i`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `ambassador` AS `a`
ON
    `a`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `admin` AS `ad`
ON
    `a`.`recommended_by` = `ad`.`user_id` LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Comment: Please post your table structure so can give correct result.

Comment: Hi nikunj, 
I have added them , the necessory ones, hope that will clerify things, 
please check above : Update

Comment: Just to clarify the question, you want to get the data in your initial `SELECT` query but with it you are getting the ids from the other tables? Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: actually the ID's stored into the ambassador table which are added from a form on front end. but to display these in the list simplet GET query gives me those ID . What I was looking for is to reveal the names associated to those IDS.

To narrow down this, 3 fields are the main , ambassador id ( which is user.user id with type ambassador ) 
institute and recommended by ( user.id with type admin )

Comment: you can try with **Ambassador** left join  with **user** and **institute** table. you can get output.

Comment: in the above query can you please write something for me which I will ultimately convert to CI format

Comment: @Wishan, Yeah correct, Please see my other update too